# How to use embeded redis in kubernetes cluster..?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I want to run embeded redis with spring boot application in kubernetes cluster but it is not creating any container with embeded redis.
Getting error: **CRASH LOOP BACKOFF**.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-registration
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-registration
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-registration
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-registration
          image: user-registration:1.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: mysql
            - name: DB_NAME
              value: user_registration
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              value: root
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: root
        - image: mysql:5.7
          args:
            - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: root
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: user_registration
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
        - name: redis
          image: "docker.io/redis:6.0.5"
          resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-registration
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-registration
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30163
  type: NodePort
```

It is working fine when iam commenting the redis config but not working when it is enabled.

Comment: CrashLoopBackOff indicates that main process in the container throws an error, the container doesn't get ready, or is continuously getting killed due to failing livenessprobe. 
there's no general solution to it. please add more information/logs to your question

Comment: When i using the emeded redis server in springboot application it is giving that error while creating the container

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please check the attached config once